# Job output in a build flow

Tags: jenkins, parameters

I have a problem in jenkins with parameters 
In a build flow, I have a job  addition( param1  A ,param2 B)

This job is written in `bash` and launched on a remote host.

```
#!/bin/sh
result=$(expr $1 + $2)
echo $result
```

In DSL I launch my job as:

```
build( "addition.sh", param1: 20 , param2: 10 )
```

How can I get the result of my job like *:30* ?

Comment: in my job, I tried to export the result in a variable 
export  RES=$result 

and in the DSL

b=build( "addition.sh", param1: 20 , param2: 10 ) 
def result= b.environment.get( "RES" )
it doesn't work.  ->  result=null